# Get list of R-squared values for linear regression model as we incrementally add predictors

Tags: r

I have a regression that predicts y based on 14 x-values (x1 through x14). I want to write a loop that does a regression where each iteration of the loop adds one more predictor to the regression, then tells me what the r-squared is. Here is my code:

```
rsqvals <- rep(NA, 15)
for (i in 1:15){
  simtemp2 <- simdata[, 1:i]
  modeL <- lm(y ~ ., data=simtemp2)
  rsqvals[i] <- summary(modeL)$r.squared
}
```

where `simdata` is my data frame and `simtemp2` is the columns I want. I suspect the problem has something to do with the fact that I can't type `simdata[, 1:i]`, but I'm not sure why not. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to include y in simtemp2.

Comment: Do you want to add predictors in order of ones which give next-most increase in R-squared, or just in order of increasing column index?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are subsetting the data.frame too much on the first iteration. In your first iteration, you would get `simtemp2 <- simdata[,1:1]`. The result of this operation is a vector in `simtemp2`. Even if you convert `simtemp2` back into a `data.frame`, `lm()` will not like it as a parameter. Try starting at 2 and see if this works:

```
rsqvals <- rep(NA, 15)

interceptonly <- lm(y~1,data=simdata) ### no features, only the intercept
### this isn't statistically meaningful, but I put it here for completeness
rsqvals[1] <- summary(interceptonly)$r.squared
for (i in 2:15){
   simtemp2 <- simdata[, 1:i]
   modeL <- lm(y ~ ., data=simtemp2)
   rsqvals[i] <- summary(modeL)$r.squared
}
print(rsqvals)
```

Comment: thanks! this code ran nicely. May I ask why you predicted y with "1" in the intercept object?

Comment: It just happens to be the notation that R uses to identify a formula that has no predictor variables. It just tells `lm()` to perform the linear regression if there was only an intercept term, so you get a horizontal line that is the mean of your `y` column